# How do you ask if you are understood without being rude?

Tags: politeness

For example explaining to an acquaintance or a stranger something, but I don't know if it's understood or not and would like to ask. In English I would say something like "I'm sorry, was my explanation clear?" to imply that any misunderstanding would be my fault. I doubt this, but would saying 分かりましたか？ carry that same sense? Or would it be impolite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

わかりましたか would be like "did you get it" so avoid it and just ask it in a way where *they* judge you and not the reverse as you did in English.

Something like 説明に不明点はなかったでしょうか。